# android application crashing with error java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android application. When i am trying to run it on emulator it crashes. It is my first android application and I am not able to find out the cause of error. Can anybody point out the mistake?

LogCat

```
    Shutting down VM
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: io.github.ishankgulati.breakout, PID: 3589
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{io.github.ishankgulati.breakout/io.github.ishankgulati.breakout.BreakoutGame}: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: void io.github.ishankgulati.breakout.BreakoutGame.<init>() is not accessible from java.lang.Class<android.app.Instrumentation>
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: void io.github.ishankgulati.breakout.BreakoutGame.<init>() is not accessible from java.lang.Class<android.app.Instrumentation>
     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
12-29 19:10:34.689 3589-3589/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3589 SIG: 9
```

You can have a look at my project [here](https://github.com/IshankGulati/Breakout/tree/master/Breakout).

The above issue has been resolved but still application is crashing.

LogCat

```
I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
I/art: Late-enabling JIT
I/art: JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/io.github.ishankgulati.breakout-1/lib/x86
E/WVMExtractor: Failed to open libwvm.so: dlopen failed: library "libwvm.so" not found
I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 33.410ms
I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: io.github.ishankgulati.breakout, PID: 2303
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{io.github.ishankgulati.breakout/io.github.ishankgulati.breakout.BreakoutGame}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'float android.graphics.RectF.left' on a null object reference
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'float android.graphics.RectF.left' on a null object reference
   at io.github.ishankgulati.breakout.MainMenu.<init>(MainMenu.java:33)
   at io.github.ishankgulati.breakout.BreakoutGame$BreakoutView.<init>(BreakoutGame.java:84)
   at io.github.ishankgulati.breakout.BreakoutGame$BreakoutView.<init>(BreakoutGame.java:51)
   at io.github.ishankgulati.breakout.BreakoutGame.onCreate(BreakoutGame.java:29)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/IllegalAccessException.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your `BreakoutGame`

```
public class BreakoutGame extends Activity{
```

is overriding the default constructor chaining its visibility. This is causing the exception. Don't do it. Every initialization, yo want to do in your Constructor can be done in one of the callback called by the framework. E.g `onCreate`

Comment: That resolved this error but now I am getting a new one.

Comment: would you share it with us ?

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I have edited the question and added current log.

Comment: add `playButton.rect = new Rectf()` before `playButton.rect.left = 0` in the Constructor of `MainMenu`

Answer (score 3):

It is because in your `BreakoutGame` activity you have an empty constructor without any [access modifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) (default is package private).

```
BreakoutGame() {
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        screenX = size.x;
        screenY = size.y;
    }
```

Please change it to

```
public BreakoutGame(){
.....
}
```

It will definitely work.

Again move your codes from constructor to `onCreate` method.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this exception since I removed public access modifier from App.java while fixing lint errors. Adding back the public keyword immediately fixed it.

```
public class MyApp extends Application
```